# Drawing a bar chart, but with some restriction

Tags: bar-chart

I want to draw a chart in linux like this:
1################# 64.85
2################### 72.84
3####################### 91.19
4####################### 91.61
5########################### 108.66
6############################ 110.69
7###################################### 149.85
8####################################### 156.60
9########################################### 169.81

I want to do that in python, of course you noticed that I don't want code like:
for i in data:
     print "#"*i
because data may contain big numbers, so it is not nice to print "#" milion times.
So what is the mathematical equation that I must use to do this, I think this is a kind of mathematical problem

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with percentages I think sum up all you values and then you do bar value / total of bar values

So if I have the following values 1 2 3 6 the total will be 12 so then 
i will do 1 / 12 the percentage will be 8 so you print '#' 8 times and so on.
then the max # you can print is hundred.
I don't know if this is what you want, but hope this will help.